# customise Popup window to contain reported errors

Tags: php

imagine i have an errors array to contain any errors from a registration form, and i have a function called `output_errors()`, whose argument is the errors array.

is there a way to customise a pop up window to display the function to display the errors?

```
<?php
$error = array();

function output_errors($errors) {
return '<ul><li>' . implode('</li><li>',$errors) . '</li></ul>';
}

if (user_exists($_POST['username']) === true) {
        $errors[] = 'Sorry, the username \'' . $_POST['username'] . '\' is already taken.';
    }
    if (preg_match("/\\s/", $_POST['username']) == true) {
        $errors[] = 'Your username must not contain any spaces.';
    }
    if (strlen($_POST['password']) < 6) {
        $errors[] = 'Your password must be at least 6 characters';
    }
    if ($_POST['password'] !== $_POST['password_again']) {
        $errors[] = 'Your passwords do not match';
    }
    if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'A valid email address is required';
    }
    if (email_exists($_POST['email']) === true) {
    $errors[] = 'Sorry, email \'' . $_POST['email'] . '\' exists.';
    }

if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
    $register_data = array(
        'username'      => $_POST['username'],
        'password'      => $_POST['password'],
        'first_name'    => $_POST['first_name'],
        'last_name'     => $_POST['last_name'],
        'email'         => $_POST['email']
    );

    register_user($register_data);
    header('Location: register.php?success');
    exit();

} else if(empty($errors) === false) {
    echo output_errors($errors);


?>
<form action="" method="post">
<ul>
<li>
<i>*All fields marked with asterisk are required!</i><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username">
</li>
<li>
<br>
<input type="password" placeholder="*Password" name="password">
</li>
<li>
br>
<input type="password" placeholder="*Retype Password" name="password_a">
</li>
<li>
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="*First name"   name="first_name">
</li>
<li>
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Last name" name="last_name">
</li>
<li>
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="*Email" name="email">
</li>
<li>
<input type="submit" value="Register">
</li>
</ul>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't customize the by-default pop-up of JavaScript, either you can use Bootstrap or do something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Test!</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200, height=100");
    myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'MsgWindow'. I am 200px wide and 100px tall!</p>");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

In the `document.write(content)`, here content will be your error message.

You can insert your php in js by doing:

```
document.write(<?php echo "Text"; ?>);
```

See if that helps.

Comment: the issue is i want pop up to be in place of the last echo line at the end of the php tag

Comment: @johngraham Have you tried to implement using bootstrap or the window.open?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but if you replace the echo statement in the last line with this:

```
echo "<script>";
echo "window.open('', 'MsgWindow', 'width=200, height=100').document.write('" . output_errors($errors) . "');";
echo "</script>";
```

You will get  a pop-up window with the errors displayed in it. That being said there are a few errors in your code which make the errors display immediately, specifically your password fields. So the above will work but you'll have a pop-up window as soon as the page is loaded.

Comment: you're going to want to look into something like this: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/ if you're looking for style